# How to duplicate line on itself?

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide

In a JetBrains editor, what is the shortcut (or trick) to duplicate a line on itself without breakline (not like <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>). In other words, I want to turn this:

```
 constructor(obj: Schema$Car) {
        this.brand =
        this.id =
        this.model =
        this.photoBack =
        this.photoFront =
        this.photoInteriorBack =
        this.photoInteriorFront =
        this.photoSide =
        this.seatCount =
        this.year =
    }
```

into this:

```
constructor(obj: Schema$Car) {
    this.brand = obj.brand 
    this.id = obj.id
    this.model = obj.model
    this.photoBack = obj.photoBack
    this.photoFront = obj.photoFront
    this.photoInteriorBack = obj.photoInteriorFront
    this.photoInteriorFront = obj.photoInteriorFront
    this.photoSide = obj.photoSide
    this.seatCount = obj.seatCount
    this.year = obj.year
}
```

Comment: Unless there is some plugin or built-in functionality (I'm not aware of) that offers this ... Multiple Carets is the way to go. Idea is: 1) create caret on each row before field names (so just after `this.`). 2) Use keyboard shortcut to select till end of the word 3) Copy into buffer 4) move into position, type `obj.` and paste from buffer.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks I figured it out after trying several things